# Get the missing value in a sequence of numbers

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I made the following query for the SQL Server backend

```
SELECT TOP(1) (v.rownum + 99)
FROM
    (
        SELECT incrementNo-99 as id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY incrementNo) as rownum
        FROM proposals
        WHERE [year] = '12'
    )  as v
WHERE v.rownum <> v.id
ORDER BY v.rownum
```

to find the first unused proposal number.
(It's not about the lastrecord +1)

But I realized `ROW_NUMBER` is not supported in access.
I looked and I can't find something similar.

Does anyone know how to get the same result as a `ROW_NUMBER` in access?

Maybe there's a better way of doing this.

Actually people insert their proposal No (incrementID) with no constraint. This number looks like this 13-152. xx- is for the current year and the -xxx is the proposal number. The last 3 digits are supposed to be incremental but in some case maybe 10 times a year they have to skip some numbers. That's why I can't have the auto increment.

So I do this query so when they open the form, the default number **is the first unused**.

How it works:

Because the number starts at 100, I do -99 so it starts at 1.

Then I compare the row number with the id so it looks like this

```
ROW NUMBER      |       ID
1                        1                 (100)
2                        2                 (101)
3                        3                 (102)
4                        5                 (104)<--------- WRONG  
5                        6                 (105)
```

So now I know that we skip 4. So I return (4 - 99) = 103

If there's a better way, I don't mind changing but I really like this query.

If there's really no other way and I can't simulate a row number in access, i will use the pass through query.

Thank you

Comment: Have you done a google search or similar yet, there's tons out there on this, I've seen some questions on here about it as well, I haven't one to hand but won't be hard to find?

Comment: I know I know.. I can't use autonumber cause this query is only for a default value. The user still can decide what the number is. Pass through queries are driving me mad so I just wanna look at other option if it's possible

Comment: Yes I did a google and I have Never found one with an accepted answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah I read that, but I don't think rank is something I want. I don't wanna compare them. I just want the row number.

Comment: @Marc That's probably because there isn't a reliable/worthwhile way of doing it, I feel you would be better asking about the problem for which you think you need to do this as there may be better options out there.

Comment: I will update my question then. Thank you. BTW why 2 vote to close... this question is legit. I did my research before and all I found was a rank or other questions with no answer.

Comment: You just want a top 1, so look at DMax.

Comment: That will return the last one. In my example, it would return 106 instead of 103 right?

Comment: @Marc The close votes are for question duplication; this question was initially "How can I have ROW_NUMBER() functionality in Access?"

Comment: Yeah, Im still looking for this. There's no question with answers on SO and the question linked in the comments here is about rank which is really different. I'm not upset but 4 close votes is a bit overeating

Comment: @Marc I'm too late for the question close sadly, but I really think you should stick with the pass-thru and take advantage of the SQL server, afterall that's what its there for : )

Comment: Hey, marc, here is a rough gap query that you could adapt: `SELECT b.akey, (select top 1 akey from table1 a where a.akey>b.akey) AS [next]
FROM table1 AS b
WHERE ((((select top 1 akey from table1 a where a.akey>b.akey))<>[b].[akey]+1))
ORDER BY b.akey;`

Comment: @remou thank you remou! Here's my final query `SELECT TOP 1 incrementNo-1 AS Expr1
FROM Proposals AS p
WHERE (((p.IncrementNo)>101) AND ((Exists (SELECT v.IncrementNo
              FROM Proposals as v 
              WHERE ((p.incrementNo-1 = v.IncrementNo) AND v.pyear = 11)
          ))=False) AND ((p.pyear)=11))
ORDER BY p.IncrementNo;` 
It works like a charm. Unfortunately, I can't give you an accepted answer. I will upvote some of your answer so you still get points for your really appreciated help.

Comment: With any luck we can get this question re-opened. I have upvoted your well-formed question :)

Comment: @Remou Thank you. the question is open now. You can write your answer and take the extra points as a bonus ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question it appears that you are looking for a gap in a sequence of numbers, so:

```
SELECT b.akey, (
    SELECT Top 1 akey 
    FROM table1 a 
    WHERE a.akey > b.akey) AS [next] 
FROM table1 AS b 
WHERE (
    SELECT Top 1 akey 
    FROM table1 a 
    WHERE a.akey > b.akey) <> [b].[akey]+1
ORDER BY b.akey
```

Where table1 is the table and akey is the sequenced number.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.Value, T.next -1 FROM (
  SELECT b.Value , (
    SELECT Top 1 Value 
    FROM tblSequence a 
    WHERE a.Value > b.Value) AS [next] 
  FROM tblSequence  b  
) T WHERE T.next <> T.Value +1
```