# Get all missing values between two limits in SQL table column

Tags: sql, identity

I am trying to assign ID numbers to records that are being inserted into an SQL Server 2005 database table. Since these records can be deleted, I would like these records to be assigned the first available ID in the table. For example, if I have the table below, I would like the next record to be entered at ID 4 as it is the first available.

```
    | ID | Data |
    | 1  | ...  |
    | 2  | ...  |
    | 3  | ...  |
    | 5  | ...  |
```

The way that I would prefer this to be done is to build up a list of available ID's via an SQL query. From there, I can do all the checks within the code of my application.

So, in summary, I would like an SQL query that retrieves all available ID's between 1 and 99999 from a specific table column.

Comment: Answer Edited.  Please try again.

Comment: See this link in Stackover flow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070244/get-the-missing-value-in-a-sequence-of-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First build a table of all N IDs.

```
declare @allPossibleIds table (id integer)
declare @currentId integer

select @currentId = 1
while @currentId < 1000000
begin
    insert into @allPossibleIds
    select @currentId

    select @currentId = @currentId+1
end
```

Then, left join that table to your real table.  You can select MIN if you want, or you could limit your allPossibleIDs to be less than the max table id

```
select a.id 
from @allPossibleIds a  
left outer join YourTable t
on a.id = t.Id
where t.id is null
```

Comment: Sadly I am getting an error saying that I am exceeding the MAXRECURSION maximum: 

The value 1000000 specified for the MAXRECURSION option exceeds the allowed maximum of 32767.

Comment: Hmmm.  Then I suppose you could build a @Table in a while loop.  I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: @user1326091  `maxrecursion` is 1 to 32k-1 or 0 for no limit. look at the corrected response. Be careful that this CTE can take quite long time. if you are going to run it online I suggest you using other methods

Comment: AHA! Working Luis's fix in with Bill's initial suggestion seemed to work but it took 36 seconds to complete the query. This is longer than I would prefer but I could limit the number of records retrieved through the code so this is not much of a problem. Cheers a bunch!

Comment: "...but it took 36 seconds to complete...." Hence, why I said doing such a thing is not recommended and is a waste of time and resources for both the person trying to do such a thing and for the processing power expended by the SQL server to do something that for it is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go for identity,

Let me give you an easy option while i work on a proper one.

Store int from 1-999999 in a table say Insert_sequence.

try to write an Sp for insertion,

You can easly identify the min value that is present in your Insert_sequence and not in

your main table,  store this value in a variable and insert the row with ID from variable..

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Answer (score 0):

You could also loop through the keys. And when you hit an empty one Select it and exit Loop.

```
DECLARE @intStart INT, @loop bit
SET @intStart = 1 
SET @loop = 1

WHILE (@loop = 1)
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Key] FROM [Table] Where [Key] = @intStart)
        BEGIN
        SELECT @intStart as 'FreeKey'
        SET @loop = 0
        END

SET @intStart = @intStart + 1
END
GO
```

From there you can use the key as you please. Setting a @intStop to limit the loop field would be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a table from 1..999999 all information you need is in your source table. Here is a query which give you minimal ID to insert in gaps. 
It works for all combinations:

```
(2,3,4,5) - > 1
(1,2,3,5) - > 4
(1,2,3,4) - > 5
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78b36/6)

```
select min(t1.id)+1 from 
(
  select id from t 
  union 
  select 0
 )

t1 
left join t as t2 on t1.id=t2.id-1
where t2.id is null
```

Comment: I lose the ability to query the database at the point of insertion due to transactions. This is why I needed the list of ID's to begin with and why I could not do a check for each individual insertion.

Answer (score -1):

Many people use an auto-incrementing integer or long value for the Primary Key of their tables, and it is often called `ID` or `MyEntityID` or something similar. This column, since it's just an auto-incrementing integer, often has nothing to do with the data being stored itself.

These types of "primary keys" are called surrogate keys. They have no meaning. Many people like these types of IDs to be sequential because it is "aesthetically pleasing", but this is a waste of time and resources. The database could care less about which IDs are being used and which are not.

I would highly suggest you forget trying to do this and just leave the ID column auto-increment. You should also create an index on your table that is made up of those (subset of) columns that can uniquely identify each record in the table (and even consider using this index as your primary key index). In rare cases where you would need to use all columns to accomplish that, that is where an auto-incrementing primary key ID is extremely useful—because it may not be performant to create an index over all columns in the table. Even so, the database engine could care less about this ID (e.g. which ones are in use, are not in use, etc.).

Also consider that an integer-based ID has a maximum total of 4.2 BILLION IDs. It is quite unlikely that you'll exhaust the supply of integer-based IDs in any short amount of time, which further bolsters the argument for why this sort of thing is a waste of time and resources.

Comment: I agree with you on discouraging the OP from feeling it necessary to keep the IDs contiguous, but his question was clear that was his intention.  As such, this isn't really an answer.  More like a long comment.

Comment: Well, we're supposed to not answer questions blindly just because someone wants to do something. I would prefer to encourage others to use good practices in the hopes of improving their craft. Sorry you had to down vote me for that--that's not very fair. If I tell you how to jump off a bridge because you wanted to, would you, even if I told you you'd die? That wouldn't be very smart.